# Stop continuously running tkinter function(s) without closing GUI

Tags: python-3.x, function, matplotlib, tkinter

I've tried a couple different things to get this code to stop (after [doesn't stop it], quit[closes GUI]).  What I found that "worked" is it throwing an error..... This bothers me.  Throwing an error, then just restarting the graph is not ideal.  I want to clean this code up (so any other suggestions are appreciated as well!)

Am I missing something?  Shouldn't stopping a function be simple?  I will post the main code, which is a lot still since there are a lot of functions.  The two that I want to stop (based off what prints out) are the update_graph and get_data.  If I say I want 5 files, it gets to 5 files (i=5), then restarts at 0 (i=0).

**What the code is supposed to do:**

First, it shows a blank graph on a GUI.  Person can set the number of files they wish to have and set up the sensor integration time.  Then, they can start the data acquisition and the graph pops up every second or so until the number of files is reached.  This last part is what I cannot get.  Stopping the file creation and the graphing when the number of files is reached.  (Note: the file creation is perfect in another code.  I am only showing this code so that I don't create a ton of files troubleshooting this).

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import serial
import random
import os
import datetime
import numpy as np
after_id = None

def get_data():
    #i=0

    rand_x = list(range(100))
    rand_y = [random.randrange(100) for _ in range(100)]
        #create a file

## In my code, this function send data through serial port from the Raspberry pi to the arduino and the arduino send the y axis data back.
##I then create the appropriate x axis
    return rand_x, rand_y


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__ (self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.running = False
        self.ani = None
        btns = tk.Frame(self)
        btns.pack()
        lbl = tk.Label(btns, text="Number of times to run")
        lbl.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.points_ent = tk.Entry(btns, width=5)
        self.points_ent.insert(0,'50')
        self.points_ent.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        lbl = tk.Label(btns, text="Intergration Time")
        lbl.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.interval = tk.Entry(btns, width=5)
        self.interval.insert(0, '100')
        self.interval.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.btn = tk.Button(btns, text='Start', command=self.on_click)
        self.btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.fig = plt.Figure()
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.line, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.ax1.set_ylim(0, 500)
        self.ax1.set_xlim(0, 100)

    def on_click(self):

        print('onclick')
        if self.ani is None:
            return self.start()

        if self.running:
            self.ani.event_source.stop()
            self.btn.config(text='Un-Pause')
            print('pause')
        else:

            self.ani.event_source.start()
            self.btn.config(text='Pause', command=get_data())
            print('unpause')
        self.running = not self.running

    def start(self):
        global interval
        self.points = int(self.points_ent.get()) + 1
        print(self.points)
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
            self.fig, self.update_graph,
            frames=self.points,
            interval=int(self.interval.get()),
            repeat=True)
        self.running = True
        self.btn.config(text='Pause')
        self.ani._start()
        print('started animation')

    def update_graph(self, i):
        while os.path.exists(str(directory) + "/Data" + str(i) + "/"):
            i +=1
        subfolder = (str(directory) + "/Data" + str(i) + "/")
        global filename
        filename = "/home/pi/Documents/Serial" + str(i) + ".txt"
        self.line.set_data(*get_data())
        print('update_graph')
        print(i)
        global after_id
        after_id = self.after(1, get_data)
        if i >= self.points - 1:

            self.running = False
            self.ani = None
            self.btn.config(text='Start', command=self.stop())


    def stop(self):
        global after_id
        self.after_cancel(after_id)
```

Comment: What does "stopping a function" mean? (It's usually hard to stop a function, because functions are meant to run until they return) Can you provide a [mcve] of the issue? Can you explain what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: Could you try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? As it is now, no one can copy-paste this code to see what it does and debug it. If you could strip code from both `update_graph` and `get_data` functions that is not necessary to reproduce the problem and just let them return something like random numbers, anyone can run it and try to help you. Please also include the used import statements.

Comment: Provided a better description.  Hope that helps.  I will now paste the import statements in as well.  Below this code is a simple def main() with root = tk.Tk() which I can add as well.

As for simplifying it, I am using a serial port.  So I am not sure how random data correlates with having real data flooding into the device (I am using a raspberry pi).  But I can try!  :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit! What I mean is the question isn't about getting the data from the serial port so all code that is there to be able to get data is not relevant for this question. Especially since people don't have your files and a raspberry pi with your configuration, including this code makes it harder to debug for other people. Returning random "dummy" data solves this. Basically, that's what the Minimal in MCVE is all about. Of course, if taking out this part of the code actually removes the problem, you should keep it in (and tell us, since that is very valuable information).

Comment: So, tried this code on the raspberry pi (with the random data) and the problem is still there.  The goal is to get the graphing to stop after the set number of files.  It is automatically set to 50.  But, I usually change it to something else like 10 if I want quick debugging/ troubleshooting to happen.  If this doesn't work for anyone, I can try to redo it so debugging is easier for you all.

Comment: That's great. I think you've been over-complicating it a bit with the `after` calls, changing the button commands and so on. Let me write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing one very important statement in your `update_graph` function and have tried a lot with `after` and changing button commands to try and fix it.

What you're missing in `update_graph` is simply `self.ani._stop()` to stop the animation when the desired number of iterations is met.

So putting that in, and removing all of the `after` calls which I don't think did any good, leaving the button command alone I come to this, which I feel does exactly what you want:

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random

def get_data():
    #i=0

    rand_x = list(range(100))
    rand_y = [random.randrange(100) for _ in range(100)]
        #create a file

## In my code, this function send data through serial port from the Raspberry pi to the arduino and the arduino send the y axis data back.
##I then create the appropriate x axis
    return rand_x, rand_y


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__ (self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.running = False
        self.ani = None
        btns = tk.Frame(self)
        btns.pack()
        lbl = tk.Label(btns, text="Number of times to run")
        lbl.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.points_ent = tk.Entry(btns, width=5)
        self.points_ent.insert(0,'50')
        self.points_ent.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        lbl = tk.Label(btns, text="Intergration Time")
        lbl.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.interval = tk.Entry(btns, width=5)
        self.interval.insert(0, '100')
        self.interval.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.btn = tk.Button(btns, text='Start', command=self.on_click)
        self.btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.fig = plt.Figure()
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.line, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        self.ax1.set_ylim(0, 500)
        self.ax1.set_xlim(0, 100)

    def on_click(self):

        print('onclick')
        if self.ani is None:
            return self.start()

        if self.running:
            self.ani.event_source.stop()
            self.btn.config(text='Un-Pause')
            print('pause')
        else:

            self.ani.event_source.start()
            self.btn.config(text='Pause')
            print('unpause')
        self.running = not self.running

    def start(self):
        self.points = int(self.points_ent.get()) + 1
        print(self.points)
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
            self.fig, self.update_graph,
            frames=self.points,
            interval=int(self.interval.get()),
            repeat=True)
        self.running = True
        self.btn.config(text='Pause')
        self.ani._start()
        print('started animation')

    def update_graph(self, i):
        self.line.set_data(*get_data())
        print('update_graph')
        print(i)
        if i >= self.points - 1:

            self.running = False
            self.ani._stop()
            self.ani = None
            self.btn.config(text='Start')


root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!!!  Thanks so much!  Can't believe it was one line, it seemed like such a big problem.  I've had this issue for a while now, so I am super happy it is finally solved.  :)

Comment: You're welcome! Thank you for taking our responses and editing the code and question as much as you did. That really helped me to be able to run your code and find the solution.